# How to get the identity which sends requests to WCF REST service?

Tags: wcf, security

I am wondering how to get the identity which sent a request to WCF RESTful service on the server side. I need to check it against Active Directory for existence and specific rights to decide whether to provide some resources in response or reject the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to ensure that the identity of the user is sent to your web service is to program it to be sent in the client software. The user ID will definately not appear automatically amongst the request http headers. If you want it, you have to put it there deliberately through code.

Probably the easiest way would be to "turn on" Windows authentication within the host/client software. Here's a link to a CodeProject demo on now to set up and use windows authentication in WCF: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/8-steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba

It does not, however, go into the AD authentication side. That will have to be done through code as well.

Best of luck.